# Truncating a single table cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to truncate/clean up a single cell of a matlab table, such as this:

important =

2×8 table

```
  Var3             Var5              Var6            Var7           Var8            Var9           Var10          Var11  

________    __________________    ___________    ____________    ___________    ____________    ____________    __________



09:13:30    'Zone="&lt;0&gt;"'    'Vset="19"'    'Vrdb="0.0"'    'Iset="10"'    'Irdb="0.0"'    'Pset="190"'    'Prdb="0"'

09:13:30    'Zone="&lt;1&gt;"'    'Vset="19"'    'Vrdb="0.0"'    'Iset="10"'    'Irdb="0.0"'    'Pset="190"'    'Prdb="0"'
```

I would like to be able to truncate Var5, to trim it down to just the number (1 or 0 in this case). I don't know if it would be best to pull out Var5 and modify it or something else.

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define

```
t = table;
t.Var5 = {'Zone="&lt;0&gt;"'; 'Zone="&lt;1&gt;"'};
t.Var6 = {'Vset="19"'; 'Vset="19"'};
```

Assuming that the number you want is just a **sequence or digits** (no sign, decimals etc), that each table entry contains **only one** such sequence (or you only want the first) and that you want the results as **character vectors**:

```
t.Var5 = regexp(t.Var5, '\d+', 'match', 'once');
```

Before:

```
 t =
  2×2 table
           Var5              Var6    
    __________________    ___________
    'Zone="&lt;0&gt;"'    'Vset="19"'
    'Zone="&lt;1&gt;"'    'Vset="19"'
```

After:

```
t =
  2×2 table
    Var5       Var6    
    ____    ___________
    '0'     'Vset="19"'
    '1'     'Vset="19"'
```

If you want the results as **numbers**:

```
t.Var5 = str2double(regexp(t.Var5, '\d+', 'match', 'once'));
```

After

```
t =
  2×2 table
    Var5       Var6    
    ____    ___________
    0       'Vset="19"'
    1       'Vset="19"'
```

Comment: or, maybe they just need to index the string :)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this now; will this allow me to call the same table, with the updated variable in the place of Var5?

Comment: @RallyToMe Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. After running this code the `Var5` column of the table will have different contents: either character vectors defining numbers, or numbers (see "before" and "after" in my answer)